# scrollTop animation works in Safari, but not Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, jquery-animate, scrolltop

This is strange. It works fine in FireFox, Safari and IE, but in Chrome the animation just doesn't work. It jumps straight to the top with no animation.

script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        $("a[href='#top']").click( function () {
            window.parent.$('body,html').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Button:

```
<a href="#top"><img src="_img/top.png"></a>
```

The whole thing is in an iframe embedded in a parent page on local domain.
When I open the iframe separately, the animation also works in Chrome!

Comment: Do you have any element of id Top in header area? According to me chrome uses default behavior first. You can use "preventdefault" to stop its default behavior.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: Chrome doesn't do a total reloading. If you have loaded the page before, everything stays there in the cache until you restart your system. Do a reboot and after that, the button must function as it should. That's if the button works properly in Safari. 
Same problem might occur when one uses Safari on iOS. Just reboot the device.

Comment: Does this issue have any connection to a system rebooting?